# How can I import a large number of new entries into Craft 3

Tags: craft3, import, plugin-import

I need to create a few hundred entries at once.  I used the Import plugin for Craft 2 to create these entries from a CSV file.

How can I do the same for Craft 3?  I do not see a plugin for this capability on the Craft 3 plugin page.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you familiar with php? Maybe it's an option to create a plugin by yourself? If you only have text and no relations it can be done within no time

Comment: That's not really an option.  I barely know enough.

Comment: I could create the script for you if you want to give it a try. Just show us the structure of your csv and what you like to import (entries, which fields). Importing data in Craft 3 is totally trivial because of Yii2

Comment: According to this Craft CMS Slack exchange https://craftcms.slack.com/archives/C04UQS105/p1519065829000362, Feedme for Craft 3 _may_ be available by the end of Feb 2018.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either the FeedMe or FeedMePro plugin for Craft 3.

Answer (score 5):

One option is to create a Craft 2 site, import the entries there, and then upgrade that site to Craft 3.